# Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab' error with latest version of React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to implement a global alert using the following approach:

[Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-alertcontext-2-forked-0bx2l1)

However, I get this error:

> ERROR in ./src/components/snackbar/Alert.js 5:0-82
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/lab' in '\src\components\snackbar'

I am using `"react": "^18.2.0"` and it seems that there is no `@material-ui/lab` installation.
How can I solve the problem without downgrading my React version? Any idea?

**Note:** I also tried `npm install @mui/lab @mui/material`, not solved.

***package.json:***

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.122",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.12",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "qs": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "recharts": "^2.4.3",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your package.json

Comment: I also tried by changing react version to 17.x, but not solved. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import is incorrect the package installed in your project is `"@mui/lab"` not  `@material-ui/lab`

```js
import { Alert } from "@mui/lab";
```

However in the sandbox you have a different package installed `"@material-ui/lab"` that's why it is working there.

Comment: I already tried it, but not solved.

Comment: What about a global implementation using Notistack instead of Material SnackBar ?

Comment: Oh our bad take a look I updated my answer

Comment: Have you ever used notistack? I could not find a proper implementation for it. I just want to implement a global implementation. Any idea?

Comment: did you saw my updated answer ?

Comment: Yes, I tried and new errors. I really fed up with to spend time with this approach and think of using notistack

Comment: Any idea for notistack implementation (global)

Comment: what error do you got ? notistack  is different from mui/lab its is not an alternative for it

Comment: why not an alternative? It seems very good and easy to use. ı just want to make a custom + global implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252473/discussion-between-ahmed-sbai-and-hexadecimal).